# Make password list with crunch

Tags: passwords

I want to make some password list like this :

```
A4B9D
```

It should has these :

1. 5 characters
2. first, third, and fifth characters are letters (A to Z)
3. second and forth characters are numbers (0 to 9)

Can this be done with the `crunch` command? I searched about that but I didn't find results.

Comment: I'm finding a lot of documentation on how to generate this pattern. Can you explain what you have tried? Also, considering that this is a simple pattern, you could script something yourself in the language of your choice.

Comment: @schroeder thanks. but i want to do that with crunch. :) it's better

Comment: It's only better if it does what you want it to.

Comment: #1 in my google search: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-r1-man-pages/crunch

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
crunch 5 5 -t ,%,%,
```

The 5 5 portion sets the min and max characters
The -t flag specifies a pattern
and taken from the man page

```
@ will insert lower case characters
, will insert upper case characters
% will insert numbers
^ will insert symbols
```